# How to use print in mongodb sharded environment

Tags: mongodb

I'm using print to debug my map/reduce queries though when I partition my database to shards the output from print is redirected to the shard where the data is stored. So how would you redirect the output from mongod instances to mongos instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no good way to do this.  When you do a print statement in server-side javascript such as a map-reduce, the print will show up on whichever server the javascipt code is executing.  When running on a non-sharded collection, this will be whichever shard is the primary shard for the database.  On a sharded collection, this could be on any shard, depending on where the code is running when it hits the print statement.

Comment: You could try running the map/reduce against test data setup in an unsharded collection first, that way at least you'll be able to know what shard the print output will go to (it will be whatever shard is primary for that database).